# Why is my filtered collection being populated by my main collection, whenever I fetch my main collection from the server?

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

I have a main collection of models that I then filter into 3 separate collections (Think categorized menu).  I have a timer to do a fetch on my  main collection to make sure it is in sync.  Each of my filtered collections is the basis for a Marionette CollectionView and renders properly the first time through.  As soon as my main collection fetch is completed by the timer, each filtered collection refreshes with the main collection's data.

**Update:** My guess is, that since I am wrapping my filtered collection in a new Backbone.Collection, The reset is applying to each of my collections that share the same models, and so the fetch triggering the reset on my collection, actually triggers the reset on all my filtered collections as well, and then populates it with the full collection.

How do I get around this?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you are sharing certain objects by reference. If you would like to contain 3 isolated collections based on some original shared state, but without creating any relation to that state, I would copy all data and create new objects. This can be done via [_.extend](http://underscorejs.org/#extend).

It is possible I may be misunderstanding your situation altogether. Some context/code would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was me. :)

I wasn't thinking, and I was creating new instances of the main collection type, even for my filtered collections.  This was creating the timer on all the filtered collections too, and was, of course, refreshing the filtered collections with the main collection data.